# AWS AppSync VTL null arrays

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, vtl

I am creating a GraphQL API using AWS AppSync with VTL templating language. However when creating a field resolver I am encountering a problem.

Code for request mapping:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "select identifier from identifiers  where client = $ctx.source.id limit 1" 
    ]
}
```

Code for response mapping:

```
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

#if($util.isNullOrEmpty($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0]))
    $utils.toJson(null)
#end


$utils.toJson($!utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0].identifier)
```

Sometimes it does not return any identifier and it returns an error like this:
```"message": "Error invoking method 'get(java.lang.Integer)' in java.util.ArrayList at velocity[line 10, column 55]"````

Anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Should `$utils.toJson($!utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0][0].identifier)` be `$utils.toJson($!utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[0].identifier)` without the second `[0]` indexing operation (which translates to the `get(java.lang.Integer)` in the error message)?